# This year is indeed passing by quickly

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

Is this a good written construction for replying a comment on which one acknowledges that time is passing by quickly?

Comment: You don't need *by*: "This year is indeed passing quickly."

Comment: Dear @Richard Kayser, thank you for your comment. I'm formally replying the sentence "Time sure is flying by". For this reason, I tried to do a parallelism. Do you think it's a bad idea?

Comment: If you're trying to do a parallelism, you might want to say, "This year is indeed flying by." "Passing by quickly" is not grammatically incorrect -- you could use it -- but the "by" is unnecessary. Hence my first comment. You could use any of the three.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. Have a good night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting question. Given the observation that the year seems almost over too soon, we say

> **[1a]** The year **is passing** quickly

but not

> **[1b]** *****​The year **is passing by** quickly.

Then we turn around and say

> **[2a]** The year is **flying by**

but not

> **[2b]** *****​The year **is flying**,

2b isn't used in spite of the fact that we translate the adage *Tempus fugit* as "Time flies".

I think part of the answer in the preference for eschewing the preposition *by* (i.e., in choosing 1a over 1b) may be found in examining cases where we do use the preposition. For example in [*For Heaven's Sake*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0uW-792knV4C&pg=PA31&dq=%22passing%20by%20quickly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikmsfQko7QAhVF6yYKHdyGCE0Q6AEILDAD#v=onepage&q=%22passing%20by%20quickly%22&f=false) by Ivan Rudolph:

> For example, "near death" experiences describe the after-life as having almost instantaneous communication, rapid travel over vast distances, "seeing" the events of one's life on earth **passing by** quickly like a movie speeded up....

When we include the preposition, we speak spatially, as though we see ourselves standing outside time, watching events pass like say, the railway cars of a moving train passing a station.  But that's not what we mean by 1a, where time has moved too quickly, carrying us along with it. I think the same reasoning fails for the case of *flying* because of the conflict with the literal meaning for flying:

> **A:** How is he getting to the meeting?
>   **B:** He **is flying**.